# Getter fallback functionality

Tags: c#, .net, episerver, optimizely

I have a class with some getters with fallbacks:

```
WebPageClass
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string Title
    {
        get
        {
            var title = this.GetPropertyValue(page => page.Title);
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title) ? Name : title;
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetPropertyValue(page => page.Title, value);
        }
    }

    public virtual string ListTitle
    {
        get
        {
            var listTitle = this.GetPropertyValue(page => page.ListTitle);
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(listTitle) ? Title : listTitle;
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetPropertyValue(page => page.ListTitle, value);
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is when I try to get `ListTitle` for an object where `ListTitle` and `Title` are null. It tries to fall back to `Title`, but it never enters the getter for `Title`, it just returns null.

I also tried using `this.GetPropertyValue` to retrieve the fallback-value, but it made no difference.

I would expect it to enter the getter when I try to get the property, but is this intended behavior? or should i use some other way to access the fallback-property?

Comment: Is it Episerver? If so add the tag. If not, what methods are `GetPropertyValue` and `SetPropertyValue`? You should try `this.GetPropertyValue(page => page.ListTitle, Title)`, so the overload with a default value(if it's episerver).

Comment: The props are `virtual`. Are you perhaps accessing them through a subclass that overrides them? Or another possibility: maybe `GetPropertyValue` returns a string containing **null** as the *text*, so **`"null"`**?

Comment: Ah, it is @TimSchmelter, I have updated the tags now. Didn't realize the GetPropertyValue was an Epi function.
I tried using 'return this.GetPropertyValue(page => page.ListTitle, Title);' and 'return this.GetPropertyValue(page => page.Title, Name);' now, but it still displays the same behavior

Comment: @PeterB, sorry I was unclear in the tagging of the question. The properties are virtual to allow Episerver to create dynamic proxies of the classes during runtime, if my understanding is correct. And when i debug the issue, i can see that it returns the `null` literal

Comment: @JonAnders: then it's not very helpful that you are not showing the correct class but a fake one `WebPageClass`. This page must inherit from `PageData`. You also don't show the code where you are trying to get the `ListTitle`

Comment: Episerver property values aren't always retrieved through the content type property getter, e.g. `myContentInstance["NameOfSomeProperty"]`. Are you saying it doesn't work even if you get the property value through `someInstanceOfWebPageClass.ListTitle`?

Comment: @TedNyberg Yes, I access the property through `someInstanceOfWebPageClass.ListTitle`, and i can step into the `ListTitle` getter, but when it retrieves the `Title` property it does not enter the getter for `Title`, and so the secondary fallback never triggers